# Visa query about Turkey

Tags: turkey, visas-on-arrival

I have ordinary Pakistani passport with valid USA visa. Can I be granted Turkish tourist visa for seven days on arrival at Istanbul airport?

Comment: If you have a valid US visa, you can avail Turkey e visa. You can't enter Turkey without Turkish visa doesn't matter what valid visa you have on Pakistani passport.

Answer (score 2):

From the official site of [pakistan embassy](http://www.pakistankonsoloslugu.org/pakistan-vatandaslari-icin-turkiye-vizesi) and [ministry of foreign affairs](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa) :

> Official passport holders are exempted from visa for their travels to
>   Turkey up to 90 days. Ordinary passport holders are required to have
>   visa to enter Turkey. Ordinary passport holders with a valid Schengen,
>   USA, UK, Ireland visa or residence permit may get their one month
>   single entry e-Visas via the website www.evisa.gov.tr.

Since you have a valid USA visa, you can apply for an e-visa from the link given above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems yes, if you have an hotel booking and adequate financial means. (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Turkey). But this is just Wikipedia.

You may need to look on Turkey embassy website of Pakistan for better information.